# Log in as a different user failed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have many Users that i use to log in into the CRM (User1,User2,...) and they all are `admins`,
the problem is whenever i need to `login as a different User` (Lets say i already logged in as User1 and i need to switch to User2) it always open the CRM as User1, no matter what User you tried to use to login, its like the browser cached the Username and its Password.

I already tried many ways to switch users like
1-open IE as a different user
2-make it as trusted site and select "Prompt for username and password" option from security tab which located in the "internet options"
3-used a separate browsers.

`Note: the CRM i use is on-premises and not IFD.`

Am confused and don't know what to do, Any idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: What browser are you using?  What Authentication are you using? AD?

Comment: Check my answer, how I do it. It works for me I have Users

Comment: I think we will struggle to answer your question without more information about your environment - is this CRM on-premises, Online, hosted? IFD or not?

Answer (score 4):

I would always do one of the following to log on as more than one user at once:

- use a separate browser
- use InPrivate browsing to open a second window of the browser but ignore the cookies that cause the problem you describe
- use RunAs to run the same browser as a different user (ideal
  for on-premises where you have separate AD accounts that relate to
  admin, testuser etc)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, iv'e already tryed that but didnt work

Comment: Which different separate browsers have you tried? Can you not run Chrome or Firefox (for example) using Run As to log in as a different user? There is no way they would share any cookies with your primary IE session, so no reason for them not to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Internet Options.

   2. Select the Security tab.
   3. Click Custom level…
   4. Scroll all the way to the bottom and select Prompt for user name and password. Click OK.
   5. Click OK again.
   6. Close Internet Explorer all open Windows.
2. Hold on shift key and right click on Internet Explorer.
3. Click on Run as different User.

[image]

Comment: No luck, still log in as admin1

Comment: didnt it asked for user name and password ??

Comment: @user3403253 Hey check my asnwer with some more details.

Comment: it did and i enterd the username field as (admin2) but it logged in as admin1

Comment: then you must have something causing IE to keep its process running when you have closed your browser window. Are you running your browser in a Terminal Services environment by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

## I know i get here pretty late...

...however i was just wondering the same and the solutions provided here and elsewhere on the web didn't solve the issue for me either. So this is what I came up with.

I created shortcuts for all users I need for testing etc. The process looks like this:

1. Create a new shortcut in a folder of your choice
2. In the *location* field paste a command applying the following scheme* (replacing the fat parts, make sure to keep the quotes):

> %windir%\System32\runas.exe /netonly
>   /user:**username**@**domain**"%programfiles%\Internet
>   Explorer\iexplore.exe **URL/OF/YOUR/ORGANIZATION**"

3. Save the shortcut
4. Make the Shortcut open as an administrator everytime:
   Properties-Window of your shortcut → *Shortcut*-Tab → *Advanced...* → Check *Run as Administrator*

---

* The */netonly* flag might not be neccesary depending on your setup